# Порт не открывается

Tags: маршрутизация

Модель роутера TP-Link № TL-WR741N/TL-WR741ND

IP-адрес `192.168.0.101` привязан к мак адресу компьютера.

Вот я добавил порт:

[image: скриншот]

Затем я запускаю http-сервер и он без проблем доступен по адресам локальной сети: `127.0.0.1:8000` и `192.168.0.101:8000`.

Теперь, я захожу на 2ip.ru, копирую там свой внешний айпи адрес, добавляю к нему :порт, у меня получается `91.223.136.211:8000` и этот адрес не работает! Порт закрыт.

Раньше, на других провайдерах, я проделывал всё тоже самое много раз и никогда не сталкивался с подобной проблемой! Может ли это вообще зависеть от провайдера и если да, то что делать? Спасибо.

Comment: Провайдер может не выдать внешний IP-адрес

Comment: @andreymal а как же работают всякие мессенджеры и торрент-клиенты, если провайдер не выдал мне внешний адрес?

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Они работают через динамический айпи вне зависимости от того, дает вам провайдер статический (внешний) айпи или нет

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf через NAT работают

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Либо вы что-то путаете, либо я чего-то совершенно не понимаю! Мой айпи всегда был динамическим (т.е. менялся при перезагрузке роутера), но для меня это не имеет значения. Раньше он был доступен извне, а на новом провайдере перестал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. На роутере сравни адрес на подключении WAN и на сайте 2ip. Они должны совпадать. Если адрес начинается с `100`,`10`,`192.168`,`172.16-32` - то доступ с интернета к роутеру невозможен.
1. Вэб сервер должен быть запущен на 0.0.0.0:8000, проверь доступен ли он не с того компьютера с которого запущен.
2. Нужно добавить порт в исключения фаервола - виндовс не принимает соединения из интернета с настройками по умолчанию.

Comment: IP адрес WAN в роутере `10.90.62.12`, a на 2ip `91.223.136.211` :( Веб сервер запускал так: `python3 -m http.server 8000`, по локальной сети доступен. Фаервола у меня нет, как и виндовс. Что ж, спасибо! Выходит что проблема в провайдере.

Comment: гдето видел сервис который может вам помочь, там даже бесплатно работает на несколько подключений, но из головы выпало название его....

Comment: я пробовал noip.com и он вроде как работает. этот сервис выдаёт мне доменное имя, к которому я могу подключаться, но позже оказалось, что ip у этого домена тоже начинается на 10, а значит никто кроме меня не имеет к нему доступа.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf нет, не ddns сервис - он не поможет. реверс прокси нужен